SwiftUI correct way to play sounds
My IOS Application has mp3 files in the project. I use AVAudioPlayer to play the sounds.  For most users and for all of our test phones it works fine. But a few users complain they don't hear any sounds. I have asked them to confirm their volume is up and the device is not muted and they have confirmed that. I also released a debug version to them via test-flight that prints out a message when the sound should play to tell me if something went wrong. It prints the sound was played.
I'm not sure why it would work on most IOS devices but not others. I have tested it on the same IOS 18 version and iPhone version one of the users is seeing it on but I can not reproduce it.
Here is my play sound method. When they run the debug version they see "Sound was Played". So I know it's finding the file and no exceptions were generated and the sound file was found.  Not sure what to look at next.
The sound files are mp3 and stored in the root project directory. But I can't imagine the location is the problem or I would have seen "Sound File could not be found" printed out.
import Foundation
import AVFoundation
import UIKit
public var muteSounds: Bool = false
var audioPlayer:AVAudioPlayer?
struct SoundService {
func playSound(soundfile: String) -> String{
    
    if (!muteSounds) {
        
        if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: soundfile, ofType: nil){
            do{
                audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))
                audioPlayer?.prepareToPlay()
                audioPlayer?.play()
                return "Sound was played"
            }catch {
                print("Error trying to play sound")
                return("Error trying to play sound")
            }
        } else {
            return "Sound File could not be found"
        }
        
    } else {
        return "Sounds are muted"
    }
 }

}

You could try this approach
if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: soundfile, withExtension: "mp3") {      do { audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url) ...}
Also use print("Error trying to play sound: \(error)")
